# Oracle OBIEE BI-Publisher, to show count of records with .csv output (not excel or pdf)

Tags: obiee, bi-publisher

Can you please share some inputs or pointers to achieve record count at end for BI-Publisher reports with .csv as output. It works with excel & PDF outputs but not with .csv

To achieve it created a Template (.RTF) and want to run BIP report using that template.

Step1:
Created a simple template using BIPublisher-Desktop and got count on one column, using BI-Publisher Field Option.

Step2: 
Use Function - <
?count(Deptno)?> -- Note:left a space before first ? so code displays.

But count wouldn't show up for .csv output. It shows up for all other formats like pdf,html,excel.

Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Version: OBIEE 11.1.1.5

Steps to Replicate:

1. Create a simple data model as select * from scott.dept
2. Create a blank layout and report on top of it to view data.
3. Using BIP-Desktop import Sample XML and load table structure into blank RTF
4. Using Field option select Calculation of count on Deptno

Sample:
Deptno
Dname
Loc
10
ACCOUNTING
NEW YORK
20
RESEARCH
DALLAS
30
SALES
CHICAGO
40
OPERATIONS
BOSTON

Count: 4

But when .csv option selected, count doesn't come up.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an eText version of BI Publisher?  Its different than RTF. It's designed to make text output, which a CSV file is.  There's a fixed width version, and delimited version.  They both operate a bit differently, and they have they own quarks compared to RTF, but they seem to work well for our needs.  There's plenty of examples seeded with Oracle for payments.  It's also documented pretty well.